# Randomly relocate the selected elements of a numpy array according to a distribution?(expand the dimensions of a 2D array to 3D by random numbers)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2D numpy array of 0s and 1s.

```
a = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1]])
```

What I need is to create a new array `a_new` according to this:
For each 1 in location `[l, k]` of array `a`, pick a random number according to a desired distribution (e.g. `shift = np.int64(np.ceil(np.random.gamma(1, 3)))`) and put it at `a_new[l, k, shift]` if shift is smaller than `N`, otherwise ignore that 1.

Here is a loop implantation of it. Is there a faster (maybe array operation) solution to this. The matrix a's size is large.

```
import numpy as np

N = 5
a = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1]])
a_new = np.zeros((a.shape[0], a.shape[1], N))
for k in np.arange(a.shape[1]):
    for l in np.arange(a.shape[0]):
        if a[l, k]:
            shift = np.int64(np.ceil(np.random.gamma(1, 3)))
            if (shift < N):
                a_new[l, k, shift] = 1
```

output sample:

```
a 
[[1 0 0 1]
 [0 1 0 1]]
a_new 
[[[0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]]

 [[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a trick using `np.bincount`:

```
a = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1]])
N = 5
X,Y = a.nonzero()
Z = np.ceil(np.random.gamma(1,3,X.shape)).astype(int)
Z
# array([ 2,  1, 15,  2])
flat = np.ravel_multi_index((X[Z<N],Y[Z<N],Z[Z<N]),a.shape+(N,))
np.bincount(flat,None,a.size*N).reshape(*a.shape,N)
# array([[[0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
#         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#         [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]],
#
#        [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#         [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]]])
```

UPDATE: With multiplicities:

```
a = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 3], [0, 10, 0, 1]])

N = 5
X,Y = a.nonzero()
times = a[X,Y]
X = X.repeat(times)
Y = Y.repeat(times)
Z = np.ceil(np.random.gamma(1,3,X.shape)).astype(int)
flat = np.ravel_multi_index((X[Z<N],Y[Z<N],Z[Z<N]),a.shape+(N,))
np.bincount(flat,None,a.size*N).reshape(*a.shape,N)
# array([[[0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]],
#
#       [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 4, 2, 0, 3],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]])
```

Comment: This is similar to what I found in my answer below. Is bin count faster than array advanced indexing?

Comment: Probably not, it is slightly more convenient because one doesn't need to preallocate the target array. OTOH, it is slightly less convenient because one needs to go through flat indexing.

Comment: Just ran a runtime check. bincount is also pretty fast. However, it is slightly slower than indexing. Thank you.

Comment: Would you have ideas for same problem but if `a` had larger than 1 integers and we wanted to scatter the integers into 1s randomly into 3rd dimension (for example if it is 3, we create three 1s at random places along 3rd axis)? Thank you.

Comment: Do the three random places need to be distinct?

Comment: They do not require to be distinct but they can be, since it is randomly drawn. Each 1's location is drawn randomly from distribution.

Comment: In case you are interested, I've updated my answer, @Ehsan

Comment: Yes, I similarly used `[X,Y] = np.repeat(np.vstack([X,Y]), (a[X,Y]).astype(int), axis=1)`. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution with advanced indexing in numpy that is significantly faster. Basically we can use non zero elements of `a` as indices to first two dimensions of `a_new` and the random values of `shift` as the indices to the third dimension of `a_new` with some filtering beforehand (remove out of bound random numbers, and reshaping `shift` array to have same shape as nonzero sub-array of `a`. Here is the working code:
import numpy as np

```
N = 5
a = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1]])
a_new = np.zeros((a.shape[0], a.shape[1], N))
shift = np.int64(np.ceil(np.random.gamma(1, 3, a.shape)))
a[shift > N-1] = 0
shift[shift > N-1] = 0
shift = (shift * a).reshape(1, -1)
shift = shift[shift > 0]
non_zero_a = np.nonzero(a)
a_new[non_zero_a[0], non_zero_a[1], shift] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try the following which may help,

```
import numpy as np
N = 5
a = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1]])
row, col = np.where(a==1)
a_new = np.zeros([a.shape[0], a.shape[1], N])
a_new[row,col] = (np.int64(np.ceil(np.random.gamma(1,3,[a.shape[1],N])))<N)
```

Comment: This one throws a shape mismatch error at the last line if you use N lower than max(a.shape). Plus the assignment can have more than one nonzero value in `[row, col, :]` while it should have either no 1s or only one 1.